# Do we use "can have" + past participle for past possibility?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

Is it possible to use Can have + Past Participle for past possibilities?
I Know  *could have* or *might have* are mostly used, but is the following possible?

> It could have been Bill's note
> It might have been Bill's note
> It **can have** been Bill's note

Comment: What does 'v3' mean?

Comment: Past participle

Comment: "I don't see how he can have been there." We don't know if he was there or not, but it seems impossible that he was.

Comment: @KateBunting: but that's being used in a *how* clause.  I think the question may have been: "Is it possible to say '*he can have been there*' as a complete sentence"?

Comment: Can  you please fix your question?

Answer (score 1):

While you might be able to invent a sentence where you can argue that *can have* is valid, the short answer to your question is **No**. Choose either **could have** or **might have**.

Comment: In the COCA corpus are a few examples like "I don't know how this can have happened." and "There is no way he can have known the location of the safehouse without the help of the inside." Note that both of these sentences involve negation. With *can* + *been* + negation, it is typically "can't have been", but sometimes the negative meaning appears somewhere else: "or as in Berneta's case in the photo taken when she can have been barely fifteen" (i.e. she can't have been more than fifteen).

Comment: Negation wasn't part of the question, and it is different. For example, "He can't have known that!" is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: It could have been Bill's note.

Correct: It might have been Bill's note.

Incorrect: It can have been Bill's note.

We can use 'cannot have' or 'could not have' when we think a past event was impossible.

It cannot have been Bill's note. or It could not have been Bill's note.